# C#/Mono in CMake on Linux

Tags: c#, ubuntu, cmake, mono

Is there a commonly accepted way of using C# in CMake on Linux?  I know it is not officially supported, as attempting:

```
project(MyProject LANGUAGES CSharp)
```

Gives the error:

```
c# is currently only supported for microsoft visual studio 2010 and later.
```

Is there some unofficial/unsupported way I can use CMake with C#/Mono on Linux (particularly Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some unofficial/unsupported way I can use CMake with C#/Mono on Linux (particularly Ubuntu)?

As of today (Sept 2022), the answer is no. There is [an existing issue ticket tracking this feature request here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/16865). You can read more about the blockers there.